# how to get google address from longitude and latitude in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get google address from longitude and latitude. I tried it but not working

```
<?php 
$sql_query  = "SELECT * FROM `user_History` where uid = '$id'";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql_query);
$i = 1;
while($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
extract($row);              
?>
<td><?php  echo getaddress($row['lat'],$row['lon']); ?></td>
<?php }  ?>
```

**My function is:**

```
 <?php
 function getaddress($lat,$lng)
 {
 $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';
 $json = @file_get_contents($url);
 $data=json_decode($json);
 $status = $data->status;
 if($status=="OK")
 {
   return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
 }
 else
 {
   return "no";
 }
 }

?>
```

**And my google map api key is here:**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey1776135765176371&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is not working. Returns **no**

Comment: You should probably reverse geocode once only and store results

Comment: But I need more than result from database

Comment: What difference does that make? Doesn't make sense reverse geocoding more than once

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand...........You should probably reverse geocode once only and store results

Comment: May you please describe it??

Comment: Get the address when you do an insert and store it.

Comment: OK...but actually, longitude and latitude stores in table from an android app. which is developed by another developer. And I have to create only admin area to show location from database. Table has only longitude and latitude, not any address.

Comment: And I am developing admin area in PHP

Comment: _“It is not working”_ - so what have you done so far to debug this? Have you removed the `@` to see if trying to make the HTTP request for that URL ran into any general issues? Have you made a debug output of the variable that you _think_ should contain JSON afterwards? Have you checked what errors trying to decode this JSON might have thrown? Why have all those things not already happened?

Comment: print_r($json);....And I got error............{ "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_", "results" : [], "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" }

Comment: How to solve it?

Comment: You are exceeding quota for exact same reason I already pointed out

Answer (score -1):

In your api you are missing api key.
According to the google docs you must specified api key.

Example here:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false'&**key=YOUR_API_KEY**

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in F:\xampp\htdocs\jaikbioapp\search.php on line 27

Comment: print_r($json);....And I got error............{ "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_", "results" : [], "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" }

Comment: The error is self explanatory: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API